# Call objective-c addSubview and removeSuperview from cocos2d-x updatemethods

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, cocos2d-x, objective-c++

I would like to call objective-c code to add a subview to the keyWindow hierarchy (in front of cocos2d-x view) and after some condition is true remove it(object removeSuperview) from either cocos2d-x update method or some runAction callback method. What is the best thread-safe way to do this? Is it ok just calling a function that will modify Apple's View hierarchy from cocos2d-x update thread? I am already aware that if you want to do the opposite (call from objective a cocos ui operation) you need to use performFunctionInCocosThread and i was wondering if something similar exists from cocos update loop to objective.